# local variable referenced before assignment json

Tags: python, json

Everything works perfect for a couple hours an then i'll get this error, an it will stop running.

```
todolist_items = len(todoalso)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'todoalso' referenced before assignment
```

I think this is the section Im having trouble with but I dont understand why.

```
    response = requests.get("https://beta.todoist.com/API/v8/tasks", params={"token":todoist_TOKEN})
if response.status_code == 200:
    todoalso = response.json()
global todolist_items
todolist_items = len(todoalso)
```

Comment: Looks like you are not getting `200` response from your api call

Comment: bcos the response status_code is not 200,define todoalso to None

Comment: Just ref the todoalso at the begining ... = =

Comment: There are hundreds of "duplicate" questions for this error. It's as simple as a variable only being assigned a value if a condition evaluates to true, and not being initialised beforehand, resulting in the variable not existing in the case where the `if` statement evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go one step further than the others and suggest this:

```
response = requests.get("https://beta.todoist.com/API/v8/tasks", params={"token":todoist_TOKEN})
global todolist_items

if response.status_code == 200:
    todoalso = response.json()
    # Let's assign this variable here, where we know that the status code is 200
    todolist_items = len(todoalso)
else:
    # instead of simply assigning the value "None" to todoalso, let's return the response code if it's not 200, because an error probably occurred
    print response.status_code
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture cases where the response fails, and log it to see why.

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    todoalso = response.json()
else:
    todoalso = None
    print response.status_code,response
```

Comment: This will fix the error described by OP, but it means they will never find out what the actual problem is

Comment: Thanks, added a print statement to find out the actual problem. Rest of the debugging is upto OP's discretion.

Answer (score -1):

In this case I would think that the response code is not 200, so it directly goes to

```
todolist_items = len(todoalso)
```

without the assignment in the if branch.
Maybe it would be better to modify it as

```
    response = requests.get("https://beta.todoist.com/API/v8/tasks", params={"token":todoist_TOKEN})
if response.status_code == 200:
    todoalso = response.json()
    global todolist_items
    todolist_items = len(todoalso)
```

As suggested by @ResetACK, I added a little change

```
    response = requests.get("https://beta.todoist.com/API/v8/tasks", params={"token":todoist_TOKEN})
if response.status_code == 200:
    todoalso = response.json()
    global todolist_items
    todolist_items = len(todoalso)
else:
    requests.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: This will stop the error described by OP from occurring, however it exposes other problems, such as, what happens if `response.status_code` doesn't equal `200`?

Comment: @ResetACK, thanks for suggestions. I have modified my answer